# Virtual Host only works when SELinux is set to permissive - why?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, selinux, amazon-ec2

Wondering why my virtual hosts will only work when SELinux is set to "permissive". When SELinux is set to "enforce" my virtual hosts are ignored and default host is shown.

**Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)**

**Here is my httpd.comf:** http://pastebin.com/2LRzLZ8Z

**Virtual files contains:**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/vhosts/foo.com/htdocs"
    ServerName mysite.com
    <Directory "/srv/vhosts/foo.com/htdocs">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Works:**

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Comment: After changing the `selinux` mode, did you restart the machine?

Comment: `/srv ` is not a default knowen folder for Apache, and selinux enforcing that. what the selinux logs have to say ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quick and Dirty Fix**

```
# chcon -R -u system_u -t httpd_sys_content_t /srv/vhosts
```

you can read more, [here](http://www.terminalinflection.com/relocating-apache-selinux/) and [here](http://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-2/issue-2/using-apache-and-selinux-together)

Comment: chcon didn't quite work for me on my Anitian RHEL7 AMI. Using semanage context -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/srv/vhosts(/.*)?" did though